# How to pass zero if input text is blank?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am getting a bit issue with my calculation, when I pass Discount and Debit values it is doing its job, but when Values of Discount and Debit is nothing it returns a blank page. Here is my Model.. CODEIGNITER.

```
function createInvoice() {
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data = array(
        'Date'              => $date,
        'Terms_Of_Payment'  => $this->input->post('termsOfPayment'),
        'Sub_Total'         => $this->input->post('subTotal'),
        'Total'             => $this->input->post('total') - $this->input->post('discount'),
        'Discount'          => $this->input->post('discount'),
        'Debit'             => $this->input->post('debit'),
        'Payment_Cridet'    => $this->input->post('total') - $this->input->post('debit') - $this->input->post('discount'),
        'Note'              => $this->input->post('note'),
        'Customer_ID'       => $this->input->post('customerId'),
        'User_ID'           => $this->session->userdata('id'));

    $this->db->insert('invoice', $data);
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use the ternary operator.

```
$subtotal = $this->input->post('subTotal') == "" ? 0 : $this->input->post('subTotal');
```

And if your php version is 7.0> then use

```
$subtotal = $this->input->post('subTotal') ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator at data array when assinging the value of debit and discount.Code is looks like as below:

```
function createInvoice() {
$this->load->helper('date');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data = array(
    'Date'              => $date,
    'Terms_Of_Payment'  => $this->input->post('termsOfPayment'),
    'Sub_Total'         => $this->input->post('subTotal'),
    'Total'             => $this->input->post('total') - isset($this->input->post('discount'))?$this->input->post('discount'):0,
    'Discount'          => isset($this->input->post('discount'))?$this->input->post('discount'):0',
    'Debit'             => isset($this->input->post('debit'))?$this->input->post('debit'):0,
    'Payment_Cridet'    => $this->input->post('total') - isset($this->input->post('debit'))?$this->input->post('debit'):0 - isset($this->input->post('discount'))?$this->input->post('discount'):0',
    'Note'              => $this->input->post('note'),
    'Customer_ID'       => $this->input->post('customerId'),
    'User_ID'           => $this->session->userdata('id'));

$this->db->insert('invoice', $data);
return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
```

}

Comment: no need used `isset` in CI `$this->input->post()` array. this already checked `isset`

Comment: Thanks from both of you. Hikmat & Razib.. Your answers were useful and solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator logic is the process of using `(condition) ? (true return value) : (false return value)` statements to shorten your `if/else` structures.

So, you can use ternary operator login for pass zero if input text is blank.

Now, some change in your `createInvoice()` function like me :

```
$subTotal       =   $this->input->post('subTotal') == "" ? 0 : $this->input->post('subTotal');
$total          =   $this->input->post('total') == "" ? 0 : $this->input->post('total');
$discount       =   $this->input->post('discount') == "" ? 0 : $this->input->post('discount');
$debit          =   $this->input->post('debit') == "" ? 0 : $this->input->post('debit');

$data = array(
    'Date'              => $date,
    'Terms_Of_Payment'  => $this->input->post('termsOfPayment'),
    'Sub_Total'         => $subTotal,
    'Total'             => ($total - $discount),
    'Discount'          => $discount,
    'Debit'             => $debit,
    'Payment_Cridet'    => $total - $debit - $discount,
    'Note'              => $this->input->post('note'),
    'Customer_ID'       => $this->input->post('customerId'),
    'User_ID'           => $this->session->userdata('id')
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
You save me. :)